# How to prevent the browser from redirecting to a new page when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I use an AJAX call to a method that returns JSON. How can I read the returned JSON without being redirected to a new empty page?

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test()
{
    return Json("JSON return test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

```html
@model List<POC.Web.Intranet.Models.AttachmentPropertyViewModel>
<div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "DMS", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "endMethod()", OnBegin = "beginMethod()" }))
    {
        <h6>Properties</h6>
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(item => item[i].AttachmentPropertyId);
            @Html.HiddenFor(item => item[i].AttachmentMetaDataId);
            <label>@Model[i].AttachmentPropertyName</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item[i].AttachmentPropertyValue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control property-value-txtbox" });
            <br />
        }
        <input type="submit" id="btnSaveChanges" value="Save Chnages" />
    }

    <hr />
</div>

<script>
    function beginMethod() {
        alert("Start");
    }
    function endMethod() {
        alert("Finish");
        // also here i want to read the incoming json
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It is hitted `beginMethod` ?

Comment: Input `type="submit"` submits the form to the controller. So change it to `button`

Comment: This has to be the most asked question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

First of all , you do not need `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` because you do a `POST` request.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test()
{
    return Json("JSON return test");
}
```

Then, change this:

```
OnSuccess = "endMethod()", OnBegin = "beginMethod()"
```

To

```
OnSuccess = "endMethod", OnBegin = "beginMethod"
```

And in your script, pass `response` parameter to get `json` result from `controller`.

```
function endMethod(response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert("Finish");
    // also here i want to read the incoming json
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the redirection and perform your Ajax calls by following one of the two methods given below.

1. Changing the button type to **button** from **submit**.
2. Or calling the JavaScript function on form submit by preventing the default action of submitting the form by utilizing the code snippet below,